# How to check if one element is exist under a form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with id `commentform` and if any logged in user visit the page a `p` tag gets generated under the form that with class `logged-in-as`. Now I am trying to check if that `p` exists and if not exists then do my validation which uses `keyup()`. Here is a small snippet...

```
$('form#commentform').keyup(function() {
        if( ! $(this).has('p').hasClass('logged-in-as') ) {
            ....
            } else {
                ......
            }
        }
    });
```

Now the problem is that the `if( ! $(this).has('p').hasClass('logged-in-as') )` is not returning me the expected result whether or not that specific `p` exists.

Can any of you guys tell me any other/better way to check this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
if ($('.logged-in-as', this).length)) {
```

But I would rather use a variable to store that state instead of relying on checking the presence of a raw tag : what if you change your HTML a little ?

Side note: Don't use overqualified selectors. `$('#commentform')` is faster and logically more consistent than `$('form#commentform')`.

Comment: Any other alternative rather than using `length` ?

Comment: @iSaumya Why an alternative ? It's the standard solution.

Comment: Oh! Actually I use `length` check in many cases and thought may be I'm not doing standard coding thats why asked.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will keep this in my mind and will never do the over qualification. Didn't knew that.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('form#commentform').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).find('p.logged-in-as').length == 1) {
        ....
        } else {
            ......
        }
    }
});
```

You can do this to find it.

Comment: The result of find is never falsy

Answer (score 1):

Check if an element witth class "xxx" exist

```
if( $( ".xxx" ).size() > 0 ) {
  // EXISTS
}
```

Edit: forgot the dot ( ".xxx" )

Comment: Please note that *"The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length property instead."* ([documentation](https://api.jquery.com/size/))

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. :)